# Get the value of specific key from JSON file python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file containing the list of price changes of all cryptocurrencies
I want to extract all `'percentage'` for all the coins.

Using the code below it throws TypeError: string indices must be integers (which I know is totally wrong, Basically trying to understand how can I search for `percentage` and get its value for all items)

```
with open('balance.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for json_i in data:
    print(json_i['priceChangePercent'])
```

Any help is appreciated

I have attached the json file here[JSON FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FkCJKsDtsrPDDRWlV6YHwdB17EbeRJ8c/view?usp=sharing)

Below is the sample of JSON file for those who dont want to open link

```
     {
   "ETH/BTC":{
      "symbol":"ETH/BTC",
      "timestamp":1630501910299,
      "datetime":"2021-09-01T13:11:50.299Z",
      "open":0.071579,
      "close":0.0744,
      "last":0.0744,
      "previousClose":0.071585,
      "change":0.002821,
      "percentage":3.941,
      "average":null,
      "baseVolume":178776.0338,
      "quoteVolume":13026.89979053,
      "info":{
         "symbol":"ETHBTC",
         "priceChange":"0.00282100",
         "priceChangePercent":"3.941",
         "count":"279051"
      }
   },
   "LTC/BTC":{
      "symbol":"LTC/BTC",
      "timestamp":1630501909389,
      "datetime":"2021-09-01T13:11:49.389Z",
      "open":0.003629,
      "close":0.00365,
      "last":0.00365,
      "previousClose":0.003629,
      "change":2.1e-05,
      "percentage":0.579,
      "average":null,
      "baseVolume":132964.808,
      "quoteVolume":485.12431556,
      "info":{
         "symbol":"LTCBTC",
         "priceChange":"0.00002100",
         "priceChangePercent":"0.579",
         
         "count":"36021"
      }
   },
   "BNB/BTC":{
      "symbol":"BNB/BTC",
      "timestamp":1630501910176,
      "datetime":"2021-09-01T13:11:50.176Z",
      "open":0.009848,
      "close":0.010073,
      "last":0.010073,
      "previousClose":0.009848,
      "change":0.000225,
      "percentage":2.285,
      "average":null,
      "baseVolume":220645.713,
      "quoteVolume":2187.75954249,
      "info":{
         "symbol":"BNBBTC",
         "priceChange":"0.00022500",
         "priceChangePercent":"2.285",
         
         "count":"130422"
      }
   },
```

Comment: Something I like to remind everyone who asks questions about "extracting ... from JSON": Unless you are having problems reading the JSON file itself, remember that JSON just deserialializes to standard Python data structures (typically a dict or list of dicts), so the question is not really a question about JSON, but about how to manipulate Python data structures (in this case extracting values for a specific key in a list of dicts, for which you can find many existing answers on SO.

Comment: In this case something like `percentages = [d['percentage'] for d in data.values() if 'percentage' in d]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract it using list comprehension.

```
percentage_list = [value['percentage'] for value in data.values()]
priceChangePercent_list = [value['info']['priceChangePercent'] for value in data.values()]

print(percentage_list)
print(priceChangePercent_list)
```

```
[3.941, 0.579, 2.285]
['3.941', '0.579', '2.285']
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is single dictionary, it could be done the following way:

```
data['LTC/BTC']['info']['priceChangePercent']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this bro

```
t = []
for key, value in a.items():
  if "info" in value and "priceChangePercent" in value["info"]:
    t.append(value["info"]["priceChangePercent"])
```